# Prove that $R- \{1,2\}$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How would I show that the complement of the closed interval $[a,b]$ is an open set.

My definition of an open set is: A subset $U$ of $R$ is called an open set if $U = \emptyset$ or if for each $x \in U$ there is an open interval $I$ such that $x \in I \subseteq U$.

I also need to Prove that $R- \{1,2\}$ is an open set.  I am wondering if getting help proving this would help with the general proof above.

Comment: The complement of $[a,b]$ is the union of two open intervals. Also, I think you meant $U=\emptyset$ in your definition of an open set, although it is not necessary to consider that extra case since the property of each point having an open interval within $U$ is "vacously" true if $U$ is empty.

Comment: Yes you are right about my definition. Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $x \in \Bbb R - \{1,2\}$, that is, $x$ is a real number not equal to $1$ or $2$.

Let $\epsilon = \min(|2 - x|,|1-x|)$

Show the interval $(x - \epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset \Bbb R - \{1,2\}$.

Comment: How do you show $(x - \epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset \Bbb R - \{1,2\}$?

Comment: If not, then $(x - \epsilon,x + \epsilon)$ must contain $1$ or $2$ (or both). Suppose $1 \in (x - \epsilon,x + \epsilon)$. This means $|1-x| < \epsilon \leq |1-x|$, contradiction. The trick to this is seeing that the interval $(x - \epsilon,x + \epsilon)$ is just the set: $\{y \in \Bbb R: |y - x| < \epsilon\}$. You can verify this by considering the two cases: $x - \epsilon < y < x$ and $x \leq y < x + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1,2\} = (-\infty,1) \cup (1,2) \cup (2, \infty)$ and all of these intervals are open, it follows that the set is open.

Comment: Would this be accepted as a proof?

Comment: Only if you have previously proved that any union of open sets is open. Textbooks differ in the order they present such properties.

Comment: I have a theorem that essentially says that an open set is a union of open intervals... it is proved in the text so I supposed I can reference that.

Comment: Also, the union of open sets is open.